# Class Not Found : Didn't find class "com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryParams" on path: /data/app/sic.example.db7-1.apk

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

Didn't find class "com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryParams" on path: /data/app/sic.example.db7-1.apk

where is RetryParams to be found?

Comment: This is a runtime error rather than compilation.  compiles fine, no "red" color for RetryParams in Android IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the jar libs you haven't add to build path.
please try:
right click on eclipse project and select build path-> configure build path -> order and export 
when check the jars you have used.

Comment: appreciated. I added the comment about this being a runtime error, compiles fine.  still debugging...

Answer (score 0):

downloaded Google Cloud Storage Client, put .jar files into /libraries (same level as /src)

added this to build.gradle

```
compile files('libraries/gcslib/appengine-gcs-client.jar')
```

added these includes to code:

```
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFileOptions;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFilename;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsInputChannel;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannel;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsService;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryParams;
```